# Why does Visual Studio not recognize my cursor trying to drag a window(Solution Explorer, Properties, etc..)?

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I'm curious if anyone else has the problem. I am using VS 2017 15.5.7 and when I try to expand or collapse a window inside visual studio it won't recognize it(sometimes). I usually have to try three to four times to expand the solution explorer window.

Has anyone experience this before and if so, how do you fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was fixed after I changed the input from VGA to display port.